# I can't export a path in illustrator

Tags: svg, path, adobe-illustrator

I want to export a path from illustrator to svg, to display it on a browser and modify it. It is a simple wave, the path is not close. But when I do it I don't have a path tag but a style tag.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="153.9px" height="39.7px" viewBox="0 0 153.9 39.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 153.9 39.7;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st1{fill:#1D1D1B;}
 .st2{fill:#FF004B;}
 .st3{fill:#CABA9F;}
 .st4{fill:#E20613;}
 .st5{fill:none;stroke:#020000;stroke-width:11;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st6{enable-background:new    ;}
 .st7{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1030_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st8{fill:#006591;}
 .st9{fill:#006895;}
 .st10{fill:#006B9A;}
 .st11{fill:#006F9E;}
 .st12{fill:#0072A3;}
 .st13{fill:#00628C;}
 .st14{fill:#005F88;}
 .st15{fill:#005C83;}
 .st16{fill:#00587F;}
 .st17{fill:#00557A;}
 .st18{fill:#005276;}
 .st19{fill:#0082BA;}
 .st20{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1031_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st21{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1032_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st22{fill:#004F71;}
 .st23{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1033_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st24{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1034_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st25{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1035_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st26{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1036_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st27{clip-path:url(#XMLID_1037_);enable-background:new    ;}
 .st28{fill:#FF0000;}
 .st29{fill:#662482;}
 .st30{fill:#93C01F;}
 .st31{fill:#009EE2;}
 .st32{fill:#F29100;}
 .st33{fill:#E61B72;}
 .st34{fill:#925F36;}
 .st35{fill:#E5332A;}
 .st36{fill:#E5007E;}
 .st37{fill:#35A8E0;}
 .st38{fill:#0000FF;}
 .st39{fill:none;stroke:#009EE2;stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st40{fill:none;stroke:#38FF70;stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st41{fill:none;stroke:url(#XMLID_1038_);stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st42{fill:none;stroke:url(#XMLID_1039_);stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st43{fill:none;stroke:url(#XMLID_1040_);stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st44{fill:none;stroke:#0000FF;stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st45{fill:none;stroke:url(#XMLID_1041_);stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st46{fill:none;stroke:url(#XMLID_1042_);stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st47{fill:none;stroke:url(#XMLID_1043_);stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st48{fill:none;stroke:url(#XMLID_1044_);stroke-width:8;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st49{fill:url(#XMLID_1045_);}
 .st50{fill:none;stroke:#3100FF;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
</svg>
```

What I want is something like that :

```html
<path d="M 100,180 L 140,0 L 180,180 L 220,0 L 260,180 L 300,0 L 330,180" style="fill:none; stroke:black"/>
```

This is what I usually have and that's why I don't understand why it is not working on that path

I follow these export settings : http://creativedroplets.com/export-svg-for-the-web-with-illustrator-cc/

Thanks

Comment: Not really possible to help you with the information provided, I'd suggest to recreate the path in a new Illustrator document (not copying and pasting) and attempting to export again.

Comment: I redid it in a new document and now it works. I don't understand what was the problem but thanks

Comment: See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBdbgD2BaEI, May be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

When the problem occurs again, save it through **export**. Not save as.

With these options -

[image: svg export options]

You will have a **path id instead** of style.

Or just dont do any export, **just copy and paste** selected layers right into your html file.